# What's my question doing in QueryXchanger?

Tags: discussion

About a month ago, I made [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085977/no-gui-after-kubuntu-18-10-upgrade-from-18-04-lts).

However, I found out just now that my post is showing up verbatim in other sites.

1. https://mail.queryxchange.com/q/3_1085977/no-gui-after-kubuntu-18-10-upgrade-from-18-04-lts/
2. https://wyldeplayground.net/no-gui-after-kubuntu-18-10-upgrade-from-18-04-lts/

I'm wondering what's up with that. I know for a fact that I did not make those posts in those other sites. In fact, I don't even have accounts with them or anything.

Are those sites simply mining other sites for content or something? Is this a case where StackExchange is providing the data in a way that they have access to (e.g. API access, etc), or is it simply that they're making regular HTTP requests and parsing the data themselves, etc?

I'm just wondering how my questions were somehow duplicated in those sites.

Comment: Use the "Contact Us" page at the bottom to report scrapers to SE Employees.

Comment: @ThomasWard What do they do about it?

Comment: Not our problem, that's something SE Legal does about it, not us.  (Report it anyways)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are those sites simply mining other sites for content

Yes.

The database is pretty much open. There is an [database explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to query the database for instance. So asking that for the last 1000 questions is pretty easy and all you then need is a website to show it.

Oh, and you only found those 2? :) If I search for my username and skip the 1st few pages of google results it starts showing tens of sites similar to that one.

Comment: Well, only those two close to the top of my results; I wasn't searching for this stuff specifically. I just ran into the by mere coincidence.

Comment: BTW, I wasn't aware of the database explorer. Thanks for the URL.

Comment: I even found a site https://askubuntu.ru which doesn't seem to be legit. Though I don't know russian. ;-)